# Are there dangers/implications to increasing max-http-header-size on a spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, http-headers

I've recently needed to increase the `max-http-header-size` on a Spring Boot application because the request headers that were being sent through from our front end was too large. I increase it from **8KB** to **16KB** and it's resolved my problem.

**My question is**: are there any implications/dangers associated with increasing the `max-http-header-size`? Is there any way it could negatively impact my application, impact performance, compromise security, etc.

I haven't found any explicit info on the subject and was wondering if anyone could provide me with more information.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Vanblerk Havenga, we are having the same issue as you, have you found any additional risks information on increasing the head max size?

Comment: Hi @LuisMiguel since I've posted the question we haven't had any more issues or noticed any adverse effects.

But as the accepted answer says, uncapped HTTP header size could expose your server to attacks, so only increase your header size to the necessary size needed to solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my understanding, Uncapped HTTP header size keeps the server exposed to attacks and can bring down its capacity to serve organic traffic.

Comment: thank you for sharing your knowledge, but could you add related reference?

Comment: I also would like to have further references but searching the web does not bring up good reasoning about it.

Answer (score 2):

One issue which I observed increasing the value of max-http-header-size(in my case 100 MB) allocated more memory to each requests which frequently resulted in Out of Memory errors when multiple requests were sent. This was observed even when the requests were simple and the header size was small.